# Represent a square of reactions with their reaction rates

Tags: chemfig, chemistry, mhchem

I would love to be able to represent a network of reactions in a square like so (pardon the scribbling)

[image]

note: I don't care about the squares around the nodes of the reaction, I can live without those.

I've been doing my reactions using `mhchem`, and I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290447/how-to-represent-a-chemical-reaction-network) showing how to display a network of chemical reactions using `chemfig`. However, I need the arrows in the reactions to show the reatcion rates, like in the picture above, and I couldn't find [how to do that with chemfig](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Chemical_Graphics#:%7E:text=chemfig%20is%20a%20package%20used,package%20to%20produce%20its%20graphics.), nor with `mhchem`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `tikz-cd` option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1.5cm, column sep=1.5cm, cells={nodes={draw, outer sep=3mm, minimum height=8mm}}]
P_{00}\arrow[r, harpoon, shift left, "k_{H^+}"]\arrow[d, harpoon', shift right, "k_{S^+}"']
    & |[red, text=black]|P_{10}\arrow[l, harpoon, shift left, "k_{H^-}"]\arrow[d, harpoon, shift left, "k_{HS^+}"]\\
P_{01}\arrow[r, harpoon', shift right, "k_{SH^+}"']\arrow[u, harpoon', shift right, "k_{S^-}"']
    & |[red, dashed, text=black]|P_{11}\arrow[l, harpoon', shift right, "k_{SH^-}"']\arrow[u, harpoon, shift left, "k_{HS^-}"]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for that demonstration of `tikz-cd`. I just wondered if you can raise the `+` and `-` in the subscripts a bit more. Making them a bit smaller could be achieved by `{\small +}`, but raising that?

Comment: Yes. There are several ways to do this. For example, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/361427/125871) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5191/125871)

Answer (score 4):

Using only chemfig

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{@{a}P_{00}} \arrow{<=>[$R_{H+}$][$R_{H-}$]}[0,1.5] \chemfig{@{b}P_{10}}
    \arrow(@{a}--){<=>[$K_{S+}$][$K_{S-}$]}[270,1.5] \chemfig{P_{01}} \arrow{<=>[$K_{SH+}$][$K_{SH-}$]}[0,1.5] \chemfig{P_{11}}
    \arrow(@{b}--){<=>[$R_{HS+}$][$R_{HS-}$]}[270,1.5]
    \schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, using the command \tiny

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{@{a}P_{00}} \arrow{<=>[{\tiny $R_{H+}$}][{\tiny$R_{H-}$}]}[0,1.5] \chemfig{@{b}P_{10}}
    \arrow(@{a}--){<=>[*0{\tiny$K_{S+}$}][*0{\tiny$K_{S-}$}]}[270,1.5] \chemfig{P_{01}} \arrow{<=>[{\tiny$K_{SH+}$}][{\tiny$K_{SH-}$}]}[0,1.5] \chemfig{P_{11}}
    \arrow(@{b}--){<=>[*0{\tiny$R_{HS+}$}][*0{\tiny$R_{HS-}$}]}[270,1.5]
    \schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't know this was possible, didn't see it in the docu. In any case, I prefer the labels on the vertical arrows being horizontal, but this is nice.

Comment: @puff -- is possible put all text in horizontal

Comment: Man the docu is so incomplete